# 413-Request Entity too large occur when uploading files

Tags: nginx, flask, file-upload, error-handling, http-status-code-413

Recently, I am building a website, and one of its functions is that users can upload a directory from the HTML page to the back-end server (python + Flask + Nginx). There is a problem when I upload more than "990" files, the 413 error occurs, even if I sent files that are larger (in Bytes) but if they are less than 990 files, the error won't occur.

I've set the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf "client_max_body_size 200M"
and flask app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 200 * 1024 * 1024

so I think the question is about the number of files, does anyone know how to solve this kind of problem?